# Why to use @ResponseBody with @ControllerAdvice in the case of RESTServices

Tags: spring-boot, exceptionhandler, controller-advice

I am learning about global exception handling in spring boot. I have a designed a controller annotated with @RestController which has a controller method that throws an exception. I have designed another class named GlobalExceptionHandling annotated with @RestControllerAdvice/@ControllerAdvice. It works fine and handles the exception when annotated with @RestControllerAdvice but doesn't work as expected when annotated with @ControllerAdvice. I am sharing my code and the responses i got on postman.

**DemoController:**

```
@RestController
public class DemoController {

    @RequestMapping("exception/arithmetic")
    public String controllerForArithmeticException()
    {
        throw new ArithmeticException("Divide by zero error");
    }

    @RequestMapping("exception")
    public String controllerForException() throws Exception
    {
        throw new Exception("An exception occurred");
    }

}
```

**GlobalExceptionHandler: (with @RestControllerAdvice)**

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler{


    @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
    public String handleException(Exception e)
    {
        return "Exception: " + e.getMessage();
    }


    @ExceptionHandler(value = ArithmeticException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public String handleArithmeticException(ArithmeticException e)
    {
        return "ArithmeticException: " + e.getMessage();
    }

}
```

**Response on postman:**
*Status:* 404 Bad Request
*Response Body:* ArithmeticException: Divide by zero error
Console: Nothing gets printed on console.

**GlobalExceptionHandler: (with @ControllerAdvice)**

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler{


    @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
    public String handleException(Exception e)
    {
        return "Exception: " + e.getMessage();
    }


    @ExceptionHandler(value = ArithmeticException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public String handleArithmeticException(ArithmeticException e)
    {
        return "ArithmeticException: " + e.getMessage();
    }

}
```

**Response on postman:** 
*Status:* 404 Bad Request 
*Response Body:* {
    "timestamp": "2020-02-15T12:41:40.988+0000",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "Divide by zero error",
    "path": "/exception/arithmetic"
}
Console: Nothing gets printed on console.

Can you explain what exactly @ResponseBody do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28646332/4214241

Comment: where do you see the use of the `@RequestBody` annotation?

Comment: when you print something to console in `handleArithmeticException(ArithmeticException e)` method. is it works?

Comment: I asked almost the same thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60182705/how-i-can-return-my-custom-json-file-instead-of-default-json-file-that-generates. I myself find out an answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60185343/12103573, which maybe can help you.